# UITextField with attributedstring not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextField` in my app that will contain some text a user types and highlight tags that are stored in the system, to make them button like. I wrote the code below to do just that for a stored text:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)parsedText:(NSString *)storedText {
    NSMutableAttributedString *gorgeous = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:storedText];
    NSArray *words = [storedText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (int i = 0; i < [words count]; i++) {
        NSString *word = [words objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([word isTag]) {
            [gorgeous addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                                    value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                                    range:NSMakeRange([gorgeous.mutableString rangeOfString:word].location, [word length])];
        }
    }

    return gorgeous;
}
```

I then assign this to a `UITextField`, like so:

```
self.textField.attributedText = [self parsedText:storedText];
```

This works like a charm. However, when I then start typing in the textfield, that text turns yellow as well. That shouldn't happen. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: When is called `parsedText:`?

Comment: What do you want to do again? Do you want the user input to be a normal text, meaning normal attributes?

Comment: Look into the `typingAttributes` property.